# Is FB.com's "Safety Check/"Crisis Response" for AI.stack or WebApp.stack if @zuck called it Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: discussion, scope, long-term-vision

I asked [**ai.stack**exchange.com/questions/10539/should-facebook-safety-check-work-if-an-account-is-stuck-at-a-name-change-checkp](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/10539/should-facebook-safety-check-work-if-an-account-is-stuck-at-a-name-change-checkp) after [**webapps.stack**exchange.com/questions/103217/will-facebook-safety-check-work-if-my-account-is-stuck-at-a-checkpoint-page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103217/will-facebook-safety-check-work-if-my-account-is-stuck-at-a-checkpoint-page) and each time the reason is that question does not seem to fit, so the asker is personally verbally antagonized because of repeating the specific grammar/[SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) of Mark's (@zuck's) exact dictated verbatim use of code/language?

To quote and repeat their apparently questionable (judging by the quick *solved-same-day-every-time-nobody-else-could-help-better-if-they-read-too* moderator responses of Stack's encouragement) wording again, *"Zuckerberg didn’t seem to have any specifics, but he went out of his way to tell me he thought **artificial intelligence** was going to play a big role in identifying moments of crisis on the network."* from https://www.wired.com/2016/11/facebook-disaster-response an AI/computer site.

I asked about the ***fact*** of if a user still gets safety notifications.

Comment: Please ignore for a moment whether the question is AI-related or not, but what is your expectation for the answer? The question seems soliciting opinion because there's no correct answer (or otherwise, every answer is correct), and that's generally off-topic as primarily opinion-based. Which is the correct answer, "yes", or "no", or "it doesn't matter"? Note that SE is a strict Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Unless you can make the question objectively answerable, then the question seems off-topic.

Comment: @AndrewT. How is there not a correct answer to if a user who is at a facebook.com/checkpoint/ page is warned about a natural disaster through Safety Check AI?

Comment: @prosody - that question is unlikely to have an answer here. And your previous posts don't seem to be asking what you asked just now. And if it is Facebook specific, why not try asking Facebook?

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext Because it's then a moral issue (whether it's a right/wrong thing to do) or policy issue (should Facebook allow it or not?), not an AI issue. Replace the "Safety Check AI" with a hypothetical "Safety Check smartphone app" and the basis of the question is still the same.

Comment: @AndrewT. I asked about the *fact* of if a user still gets safety notifications.

Comment: Prosody - it looks like your posts say "should", and while I still cannot align the wording in them with what you are speaking about here, should is a moral issue as Andrew says.

Comment: @RoryAlsop My moderators on Quora.com changed a significant number of my questions to the prefix "Should"/"Would" and I did not fight, that might be trauma then? What word is objective?

Comment: I think you made the current question too complicated written. Your previous comment is the question that I can easily understand and objectively answerable: "Do FB users on name change checkpoint still receive safety check notification?". Now, I don't know if company's policy related question is on-topic or not on [webapps.se], but if it's on-topic, then that's the question you should ask. (Note that I can't see your deleted question on [webapps.se], so I don't know the question you had posted on there)

Comment: @AndrewT. Okay I can go with that, it's my original question just said another way.  However, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/103217/13 reworded similarly (do you have enough reputation to read? (Edit: I wrote that before you edited again, if keylog tracked)) and led to still harsh words, I am worried you do not have enough reputation to help counter the crowd.

Comment: Well, then [meta.webapps.se] is the place to discuss about your question...

Comment: @AndrewT. How many times do I recreate a question uncertain if that is the amount that is too far and find another crowd (a moderator from before is already here saying I do not speak English again, after US Public Schools) of angry moderators? ...is there any effort to assist existing questions or is the goal to make multiplle questions and have me worried about counting?

Comment: I mentioned *Meta* WebApps.SE, not the main WebApps.SE. It's the place to discuss and request for feedback how to improve your now-deleted question on there. Assuming [website's policy is on-topic](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/are-questions-regarding-website-policies-on-topic), then the core of the question should be on-topic, unless shown otherwise by their community.

Comment: @AndrewT. My experience with Quora.com is that if I keep making another question at some point that itself becomes a moderation reason. I have existing questions for commenters to congregate if a discussion is necessary first, otherwise I am scared to make an additional question while being publicly flogged.

Comment: Since I can't see deleted post on there, did you receive any actionable feedback/comments to improve your post? If yes, then follow their suggestion. If not, then you can ask for feedback on *how to make your question on-topic (if possible)* on their meta. While SE is **not** Quora, you're right that if you repost the same question, then it's wrong. But SE **allows** any users to request for constructive feedback on their meta site. Otherwise, I'm afraid I can't help you anymore on this issue...

Comment: @prosody - quora is very different to Stack Exchange. Please don't use experience there as indication as to what is needed here. And what do you mean by "that might be trauma then"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[At the time](https://ai.stackexchange.com/revisions/10539/7) I read the question for the first time, this is what I interpreted:

- **Title**: "Should" suggests that the question was eliciting opinions of the readers, whether "yes", "no", "doesn't matter", etc., which is opinion-based (off-topic) because there's no one correct answer, or every answers are correct.
- **1st paragraph**: According to your personal experience, "Safety Check" doesn't seem to work when you're stuck on "Name Change Checkpoint" page.
- **2nd paragraph**: According to Zuckerberg, "Safety Check" is using AI.
- **3rd paragraph**: More explanation about "Safety Check", particularly about it not being able to be moderated by public users (i.e. fully automatic)?
- **4th paragraph**:  Explanation about checkpoint page and Name Change Checkpoint page
- **2 list items**: Meta commentary that there are no related questions about "Safety Check" on AI.SE
- **5th paragraph**: Meta commentary, and a slight hint of another question ("*what is important for a question about safety*"), and a comment about "911 case" (globally recognized), "211 case" (I never heard about that until I googled it), and "911 API" (also not sure, but based on googling, perhaps an emergency reporting system)

So, after finished reading this, the question left me with the impression that it is opinion-based (title) and too-broad (5th paragraph).

---

Regarding the title of the meta discussion,

> Is FB.com's “Safety Check/”Crisis Response" for AI.stack or WebApp.stack if @zuck called it Artificial Intelligence?

As I'm not a regular of this community, I don't have enough knowledge to determine if it's on-topic or not.

*Perhaps* the inside work/mechanic of the feature *might* be on-topic, e.g. "*How does Facebook's 'Safety Check' recognize a crisis and alert the relevant user?*" looks like AI-related. (Note again, whether it's really acceptable question or not, I can't answer that as I'm not a regular)

However, for your specific question on AI.SE, reading from the title and the non-existence of the explicit question on the body made me assuming that you're asking if Facebook *should* work or not on a particular case. Most possibly due to language barrier/misunderstanding (note: I'm not a native English speaker), I read the question as a moral question ("is it right/wrong if FB is not doing this?") or a company's policy question ("does FB do this?"), which is certainly off-topic on this site, because *the core question* is not related to AI at all.

This is an example case of ["boat programming"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/241919), i.e. just because Zuckerberg stated that FB's "Safety Check" is done by AI, doesn't mean this question is automatically on-topic on AI.SE.

---

After the back-and-forth comments on this meta question and [the revision to it](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1495/2), looks like the real question is

> I asked about the fact of if a user [currently stuck on checkpoint] still gets safety notifications.

This is a clear question about *the current policy of Facebook*. While this is off-topic on AI.SE, this looks like on-topic on WebApps.SE based on their meta discussion: [Are questions regarding website policies on-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/97)

Apparently, you have [posted the question on WebApps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103217/will-facebook-safety-check-work-if-my-account-is-stuck-at-a-checkpoint-page) before posting here, but it's been deleted, and according to you, you got angry comments. I believe the core question is on-topic on WebApps.SE, but perhaps the wording gave the readers wrong impression. While I can't see deleted posts on there (so I won't judge anything), the correct place to discuss and request for feedback on how to improve your question is on their meta site, [Web Applications Meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Okay, if formally citing me adding the singular word "fact" https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1495/2 is supposed to be encouragement, that attempt might work. I almost never vote for answers just questions so you are now +1 special. I do not know how I feel about being popular first (my 1st question taking me apart with a long answer had to be here?:) for meta (super meta?) moderation questions.

Comment: Can I vote for just the line number with Git Blame https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame? Partial vote? ~3.7%? of your citation?

Comment: Is .meta. actually .moderation. and secretly public (did I miss that with Quora.com:)? Is that why you are all always crowded telling me to go to "ask another question", you all mean ask Meta==Moderation, and that is now a colloquial passing synonym here, even though being called meta usually meant verbal abuse that you/me are being taunted in *any other* context in real life with how being called "meta" means a slur? Usually "ask another question" (partly what I called "angry") means "go away" does not necessarily mean "try". Now I am learning Meta means Moderation basically?

Comment: I will link/credit you for your wording of "I asked about the fact of if a user [currently stuck on checkpoint] still gets safety notifications." once I re-ask.

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext Every SE site has its own meta site, and it might help to understand [what "meta" is and how it works](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Apparently ".Meta" is too abstract for me (I know that's funny almost, me being meta and abstract too), I think ".Moderation" would have worked. The mod chats were called mod chats FWIW. Thank you for helping me with my first meta questions here and now https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/specification-of-facebook-safety-check-crisis-response-being-about-the-feature (https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/4619/2), feel free to edit me if you think of better wording.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of those questions, nor this one make any sense to me. I have read and re-read trying to understand what you mean, and I honestly have no idea.

I would vote either of those ones as unclear what you are asking, or possible offtopic, and have to also vote this one as unclear.

There seems to be a language challenge here. The body of your questions doesn't align with the titles. The titles seem like off topic questions, but the body of the questions is all over the place.

Comment: I was exactly wondering the same thing. Is it me or does the question look somewhat Incoherent?